# VBA code for calculating percentage of each year in a date range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CalculatePercentageByYear()

    ' Define variables for start date, end date, and percentage by year
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim percentageByYear() As Double
    
    ' Get the start date and end date from cells DTH1 and DTI1
    startDate = Range("DTH1").Value
    endDate = Range("DTI1").Value
    
    ' Get the date range corresponding data values
    Dim dateRange As Range
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim dateCell As Range
    Dim dataCell As Range
    Dim yr As Integer
    Dim cellsInRange As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set dateRange = Range("B1:DTG1")
    Set dataRange = Range("B2:DTG28")
    
    ' Calculate the total number of cells in the data range
    Dim totalCells As Double
    totalCells = dataRange.Cells.Count
    
    ReDim percentageByYear(1 To 1, 1 To 14)
    
    For i = 1 To 14
        ' Get the date cell and data cell for the current year
        Set dateCell = dateRange.Cells(i)
        Set dataCell = dataRange.Cells(i)
        
        ' Get the year from the current date cell
        yr = Year(dateCell.Value)
        
        ' Check if any non-empty cells are present in the data range
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(dataRange.Columns(i)) > 0 Then
            ' Calculate the percentage of difference between end date data value and start date data value
            Dim startDateDataValue As Variant
            Dim endDateDataValue As Variant
            On Error Resume Next
            startDateDataValue = dataRange.Cells(Application.Match(startDate, dateRange, 0), i)
            endDateDataValue = dataRange.Cells(Application.Match(endDate, dateRange, 0), i)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If IsError(startDateDataValue) Or IsError(endDateDataValue) Then
                percentageByYear(1, i) = "N/A"
            ElseIf startDateDataValue = 0 And endDateDataValue = 0 Then
                percentageByYear(1, i) = 0
            ElseIf startDateDataValue = 0 Then
                percentageByYear(1, i) = -1
            Else
                percentageByYear(1, i) = ((endDateDataValue - startDateDataValue) / startDateDataValue)
            End If
        Else
            percentageByYear(1, i) = 0 ' Set percentage as 0 if no non-empty cells are found
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Output the percentage by year row-wise to cells DTH2 and below
    Range("DTH2").Resize(1, 14).Value = percentageByYear
    
    ' Add table and set table style
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    On Error Resume Next
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        tbl.Delete
    End If
    
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("DTH2:DTZ28"))
    tbl.Name = "Table1"
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium16"
    
    ' Set the table headers to the corresponding years
    For i = 1 To 14
        tbl.ListColumns(i).Name = "Year " & 2010 + i - 1
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

i want to calculate the percentage of each year from 2010 to 2023 in between two date range by entering start date and end date of current month and year. i am using above code but its output not coming. what is wrong?

Comment: Some feedback for you: you are doing too much at once, and your requirements are not clear from the text. You could give us a small example of an input sheet and the output that you expect from it, then someone will be more willing to help.

Comment: First problem: you seem to be overloading `i` with meanings. If your outer loop is really `i = 1 to 14`, then I would expect `yr = 2010 + i - 1`. But you are looping over `dateRange` cells, so it should be `i = 1 to totalCells`. You also have 27 lines (2 to 28) and no loop over that number. I think `startDateDataValue` should be calculated 27 times. Finally, I believe you want `percentageByYear(1 To 27, 1 To 14)` or, better, `percentageByYear(2 To 28, 2010 To 2023)`.

Comment: Second problem: you never adjust `startDate` and `endDate`. I believe you want something like `startDate = DateSerial(yr, Month(startDate), Day(startDate))`, so that you consider one year at a time. In this case, `i` is the year and you do not want to loop over `dateRange.Cells(i)`.

Comment: This line: `Range("DTH2").Resize(1, 14).Value = percentageByYear` will make much more sense when you dimension `percentageByYear(1 to 27, 1 to 14)`. The way it is, only one line will be written, ever.

Comment: I think this is reversed: `dataRange.Cells(Application.Match(startDate, dateRange, 0), i)` should be `dataRange.Cells(j, Application.Match(startDate, dateRange, 0))`, because your dateRange is horizontal and `Match()` will return a column. The variable `j` is the line from 2 to 28, but this loop is currently missing.

Comment: @emilio you i right in some cases but startDate and EndDate are getting values in line 7,8. Maybe you didn't notice the first part of the code in the scroll window.

Comment: @Blackcat, they are set and stay fixed, without more information I am not sure whether they should stay fixed or not.